# HDD Partitioning on Ubuntu 14.10

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive

I have installed Ubuntu 14.10 on my laptop. I tired to partition HDD but i could not.
I used `gparted` and disk utility, and still I am unable to partition my HDD. I have 500gbp HDD.

I used Disk utility and tried to unmount it says:

> Error unmounting /dev/sda4: Command-line `umount  "/dev/sda4"' exited
>   with non-zero exit status 32: umount: /: target is busy
>           (In some cases useful info about processes that

I used gparted to unmount it says

> The partition could not be unmounted from the following mount points:
>
> /
>
> Most likely other partitions are also mounted on these mount points.
>   You are advised to unmount them manually.

i tired to create new partition table from gparted it says

> 3 partitions are currently active on device /dev/sda.

Comment: If you are trying to modify `/`  partition, you have to run Ubuntu in live mode. But before you do it, I will suggest you to read few partitioning documentation provided by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change a mounted and active partition! It is dangereous! To do that, boot from a live disk (CD, DVD or USB key), and run from there `gparted`.

And, please, never ever do that again from a running system.

Comment: Thannks you i have sucesfully parted my HDD from Live disk.